# g++ Compiler Error using ROSE Compiler Framework

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, rose-compiler-framework

I compiled the Rose Compiler framework successfully.

However, I am having difficulty using the Rose compiler for C++ code due to g++ internal header file issues. I tried googling without luck on a solution.

I have a very simple C++ file `foo.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

return 0;

}
```

When I run the rose compiler tool:

```
rose_install/bin/astTraversalTest foo.cc
```

The errors I get are:

```
starting frontend
"/home/user/klall/tools/rose_install/include/g++_HEADERS/hdrs3/bits/c++config.h", line 1608: error: 
          expected a ";"
    using namespace__debug__attribute__ ((strong));
```

Any idea why I am getting this problem? Is there a `#define` I have to set or something else?

I don't have an issue with C header files like <\stdio.h>

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this problem, I believe it is due to this:
http://www.rosecompiler.org/FAQ.html
I get an "visibility" error using ROSE 
Using ROSE to parse code in form of : **attribute**((visibility("default"))) will not work right now as we currently support EDG 3.3 and there is no easy way to support this. We are currently porting to EDG 4.0 where this problem will be solved. What can I do? If you try to include mpi.h, try to define OMPI_DECLSPEC to empty space: "#ifndef OMPI_DECLSPEC ". This should help get around that problem for now.